# Android Parse Notification cannot receive notification if push form our server

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm using parse notification in my project.

I have received notification successfully if push from Parse console.But when it push from our server I cannot get the notification. Btw, this code from server also supply to iOS and iOS device got the notification.

The notification will push from our server to Parse and Parse will send to Android device.
Kindly advise and thank you for any kind help.

My Manifest :

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
     <permission
            android:name="com.zukami.apps.dev.blynk.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
            android:protectionLevel="signature" />

        <uses-permission android:name="com.zukami.apps.dev.blynk.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

  <!-- Push notification -->
        <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="com.zukami.apps.dev.blynk" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.zukami.apps.dev.blynk.util.BlynkParseBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <!-- End of push notification -->
```

My Application class:

```
 @Override
          public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            Parse.initialize(this, "YOUR_APP_ID", "YOUR_CLIENT_KEY"); 
            PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this,PushActivity.class);        
        ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("testChannel", new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(com.parse.ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    Log.e(TAG,
                            "successfully subscribed to the broadcast channel.");
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "failed to subscribe for push", e);
                }
            }
        });
          }
```

My Activity class :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.display_promo_activity);

        spinner = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        fragment = new Fragment();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment, PROMO_POPUP);
        transaction.commit();

        // Track app opens.
        ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            mData = extras.getString("com.parse.Data");
            Log.e(TAG, "DATA ORIGINAL = " + mData);

            if (mData != null) {
                mData = mData.replace("\\", "").trim();
                mData = mData.replace("\"{", "{").trim();
                mData = mData.replace("}\"", "}").trim();
                Log.e(TAG, "AFTER REPLACE = " + mData);
                try {
                    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(mData);
                    JSONObject alertObj = jObject.getJSONObject("alert");
                    JSONObject dataObj = alertObj.getJSONObject("Data");
                    action = dataObj.getString("Action");
                    JSONObject innerDataObj = dataObj.getJSONObject("Data");
                    id = innerDataObj.getString("id");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                }

            }
        }

    }
```

My Broadcast class :

```
 @Override
        public void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.e("Push", "Clicked");
            Intent i = new Intent(context, PushActivity.class);
            i.putExtras(intent.getExtras());
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
```

This is the code from server to make push notification :

```
  var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
               string endPoint = "https://api.parse.com/1/push";
               string applicationID = "APP_ID";
               string restAPIKey = "REST_API_KEY";
               PushNotificationAction data = new PushNotificationAction();
               data.Action = "ViewAction";
               data.alert = "Alert action for android";
               data.Data = new PushNotificationActionData()
               {
                   id = ActionID
               };

               var client = new RestClient(endpoint: endPoint,
                               method: HttpVerb.POST);

               client.Headers = new List<string>();
               client.Headers.Add(string.Format("X-Parse-Application-Id: {0}", applicationID));
               client.Headers.Add(string.Format("X-Parse-REST-API-Key: {0}", restAPIKey));

               PushActionNotification push = new PushActionNotification();
               push.channels = new List<string>();
               push.channels.Add("");

               push.data = new PushNotificationActionItem()
               {
                   Data = jss.Serialize(data),
                   content_available = 1
               };
               string jsonData = jss.Serialize(push).Replace("content_available", "content-available");
               client.PostData = jsonData;
               client.ContentType = "application/json";
               var json = client.MakeRequest();

               response.Status = 1;
               return response;


public class PushNotificationAction
{
   public string Action { get; set; }
   public PushNotificationActionData Data { get; set; }
   public string alertMsg { get; set; }
   public string alert { get; set; }
}
public class PushNotificationActionData
{
   public string id { get; set; }
}

public class PushNotificationActionItem
{
   public string Data { get; set; }
   public int content_available { get; set; }
}
public class PushActionNotification
{
   public List<string> channels { get; set; }
   //public string type { get; set; }
   public PushNotificationActionItem data { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: As you said there is no issues when you push from parse right ?. Then issue might be in the code that pushes notification from your server to parse. post that code.

Comment: Hi @John , thanks for your reply, please find my edit code above

Comment: Where are you adding the data to pushed for example: \n
"alert": "Alert message."

Comment: Hi @John, I post more detail code to push the notification. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found the solutions!!

The problem is in JSON data. The same JSON data that push to iOS cannot push to Android, so I decide to divide push notification for Android and iOS. For Android the template JSON will be like following below  :

```
{
    "data": {
        "Action": "ViewAction",
        "Data": {
            "id": "1432f1ea-33c4-4528-a695-7412a7a7499a"
        },
        "alertMsg": null
    },
    "title": "Alert action for android",
    "alert": "Alert action for android",
    "push_hash": "d265b3500c1089dc0c7c9ace251cfebb"
}
```

Here's the short description :

1. data --> put your JSON payload as a value of this JSOn key
2. title --> this value will be as your android notification description
3. alert --> this value will be as your android notification title.

I post this answer maybe it will be useful for someone in future,
Cheers..